# Does "Google Webmaster Tools" service send notification if finds broken links?

Tags: google-search-console

Can GWT email me if a broken link is found on my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not for single broken links. It will, however, notify you of large and sudden changes; for example spikes in the number of 404s, soft 404s, server errors, etc.

Your best bet is to periodically check your site with a crawler like [Xenu](http://xenus-link-sleuth.en.softonic.com) or [Screaming Frog](http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/).

Answer (score 1):

Google Webmaster will only email you if it finds critical issues with your site.
For example, it will email you if it detect malware on your site or see a significant increase in errors while crawling your site.

They recently announced this via their blog: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/10/keeping-you-informed-of-critical.html

You can change some of those notifications by going to your email notification preferences.
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/preferences